# import torch error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.hub'"

Tags: python, torch

I encountered an error when importing torch. I tried to reinstall torch but the error still persists

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 4>()
1 import pandas as pd
3 import torch
----> 4 import torchtext
5 from torchtext.vocab import vocab
6 from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchtext_*init*_.py:3, in 
1 import os
----> 3 from torch.hub import _get_torch_home
5 # the following import has to happen first in order to load the torchtext C++ library
6 from torchtext import _extension  # noqa: F401

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.hub'

[image]

Comment: We would appreciate it if you could show us a snippet of your code or some information about your envirionment. I ran both `import torch` and `import torch.hub` on my computer and they imported correctly.

Comment: Hi, added a picture to my comment above.

Comment: What's your `torch` version? You can check it by printing `torch.__version__`.  You might be using an outdated version of PyTorch. Try installing the latest version and see if the error persists.